# web servers - How to specify server being used

Tags: php, jquery, python, apache, webserver

I am writing a simple web server. This is the Python code I have:

```
import http.server

from os import curdir, sep

class RequestHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path.endswith(".php"):
            f = open(curdir + sep + self.path)

            self.send_response(200);
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/php")
            self.end_headers()

            self.wfile.write(f.read())
            f.close()

        else:
            self.send_error(404, "Cannot open non-html file")

httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(("", 8000), RequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

And this is the HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hello</title>    

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Click me" id="button">

        <script>

            var buttonOnClick = 
                function() {

                    var updateButton =
                        function(result) {  
                            $("#button").replaceWith("<p>" + result + "<p>");
                          };


                    $.get("text.php", updateButton);
                };

            $("#button").click(buttonOnClick);  

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

text.php

```
<?php  
        echo "Hello!";  
?>
```

When I run this with Apache on, I get the expected results. The button changes to "Hello!" when you click it. When I run it with Apache off, however, the page shows an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error. This tells me that my webpage is using Apache as its server and not my Python code. I cannot figure out how to make my HTML and jQuery code use my custom web server instead of Apache. This might be a really simple question, but I am stumped.

And if there is anything that I can improve in my code, please let me know.

Comment: The custom server is running on port 8000. Did you put `:8000` after the server name in the URL?

Comment: I tried using `https://localhost:8000/webprograms/testwebserver/index.html`. It gave me an SSL connection error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port number goes after the hostname in the URL, not at the end.

And since your HTTP server doesn't have SSL enabled, you have to use `http:` as the protocol, not `https:`.

So the URL should be `http://localhost:8000/webprograms/testwebserver/index.html`

Comment: It said "No Data received", which I am assuming is a programmer error. How do I fix this in the Python code?

Comment: Is `webprograms` a subdirectory of the your current directory when you run the webserver?

Comment: The directory in which all of these files are located is `C:\xampp\htdocs\WebPrograms\TestWebServer`.

Comment: What is your current directory when you run the Python script? Since you concatenate the URL path to the current directory, you need to run the program from `\xampp\htdocs` to access the files with that URL.